# mailto: links not working if Chromium browser is the default Email software

Tags: html, google-chrome, mailto

I noticed this issue occurring in the past few weeks, and never experienced it before. Basically, In Windows, if I set the default Email to Chrome, `mailto` links no longer work properly. The browser I am using to click on the link produces different results, but none of them work correctly.

Step-by-step, what I'm doing is:

- In Windows > Default apps > Email - set to Chrome
- In ANY browser, click a `mailto` URL

  - Chrome: Nothing happens
  - Firefox: Opens new, empty Chrome window

If I set the Default Email to use Firefox, the `mailto` URLs work fine from all browsers.

Here is some HTML code I was able to reproduce the bug in:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>
    <a href="mailto:anyemail@email.com">This is a test.</a>
  </body>
</html>
```

I am inclined to believe this may be a bug between Windows and Chrome, because this only very recently started happening.

Some things I tried include:

- Changing Chrome Privacy settings
- Other threads suggested Handlers settings in Chrome, which did not solve this
- Verify the default program was set correctly (Default Programs > Associate a file type or protocol with a program)
- Use `window.open` instead of `href` (not that this would be a good solution, but it yielded similar results)